# Python socket.connect() errors out

Tags: python, sockets

Python version 2.7.3

Python code, interactive mode

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("192.168.95.148",21))
```

Errors out

```
>>> s.connect(("192.168.95.148",21))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Syntax looks correct. I even tried with another IP address that is pingable and same error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am looking at the port you are using (21) and it's the FTP port.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

I don't see any errors in your code per se, but here some things I am worried about:

a) A lot of places lock down and turn off `FTP`, `telnet`, etc. ports
     that are historically used, but in today's security consious world,
     we use `scp` and `ssh` (instead of `ftp` and `ssh`).  You might talk to your
     system administrators and see if that service is even turned on,
     or let alone your filewall even allows that port to go through.

b) I am not used to seeing the default parameters, but I assume you 
     want

> socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

I have Python 2.6, and that is the defaults for that (which I assume
   is the same for 2.7).

c) I would try this on different ports to see if it is a port problem.
     Of course, the early numbered ports are special "well-known ports" that
     normal users can't use.   I usually use port 9711 or 8888.

d) I would also try it without the timeout and see if that works.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I am learning from "Violent Python" for study. Will try this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but if you're seeking to do FTP transfers, may I suggest to use the standard [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html) module instead?